# Simple Events in Bernoulli Space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Want to write the following events in Bernoulli space$\Omega=\{\omega=(\omega_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | \omega_n \in \{u,d\}   \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ in terms of the simple events $E_n=\{\omega\in \Omega | \omega_n=u\}$.
(i) Sequence $udu$ comes up eventually
(ii) Price never goes up 5 times in a row
Also want to know which of the events belong to the algebra generated by the simple events.
I know the answer involves infinite unions ans intersections but I'm getting confused with the notation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`udu` comes up eventually, means there is some time point $k$ such that $E_k$ occurs (i.e. `u` comes up at time $k$), $E_{k+1}^\complement$ occurs (`d` comes up at the next time point)  and finally $E_{k+2}$ also occurs (to complete the `udu` sequence). This could happen at any $k$ so we need a union (there exits some $k$ etc).

So the event is (in terms of the $E_k$):

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (E_k \cap E_{k+1}^\complement \cap E_{k+2})$$

(ii) is that never we have `uuuuu`. We could simply apply the previous idea and take the complement.

We get (summarising $E_{k}\cap E_{k+1} \cap E_{k+2} \cap E_{k+3} \cap E_{k+4}$ by $\bigcap_{n=0}^4 E_{k+n}$)

$$\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=0}^4 E_{k+n}\right)^\complement$$

which de Morgan tells is is equivalent to

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=0}^4 E_{k+n}^\complement$$

if you prefer that.

Both of these are in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $E_k$, of course, because we essentially need the infinite unions or intersections.